# how can map the hibernate criteria resultset to the java class?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

i have a entity with many field,i need to get some of them with a query and save in a java class?
i know how can set projections and get Specified field ,but i don't know how to map resultset to java class.

> this is my query:

```
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(EmployeeInfo.class);
    Criterion condition1= Restrictions.eq("employeeTO.id",id);  
    criteria.add(condition1);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("name"))
            .add(Projections.property("birthDay")));
```

> i need to save result to list of below class

```
public class SubEmployeeInfo{
    String name;
    int brithDay;
}
```

How can I save `critria.list()` into a `List<SubEmployeeInfo>`?

> i have used below code but all field of returned SubEmployeeInfo object is null

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(HokmKargoziniDTO.class));
SubEmployeeInfoList = (List<SubEmployeeInfo>) criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `setResultTransformer` method while building [criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html). [ResultTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) objects can create you marshaling results to any desired format.

Example:

`criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SubEmployeeInfo.class));`

Comment: thank;s,i used this method but in created SubEmployeeTO object all field is null.